# Issue with Unmanaged callback in Windows Forms. Access Violation

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I am having an issue getting a third party .dll which uses unmanaged callbacks to work in a c# forms project. Initially the program would crash after the first call to the callback. However, the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411110/access-violation-exception-crash-from-c-callback-to-c-function) helped me solve that issue (Cdecl was the right calling convention). The callback definition in C# looks like:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void FrameDelegate(IntPtr lpContext, IntPtr bpData, int nDataSize, int nChannel, int isKeyFrame, int nFrameCnt);
```

The actual callback looks like:

```
    public void FrameDelegate(IntPtr lpContext, IntPtr bpData, int nDataSize,
        int nChannel, int isKeyFrame, int nFrameCnt)
    {
        lock (ChannelStats)
        {
            ChannelStats.TotalSize += nDataSize;
            ChannelStats.CurrentFileSize += nDataSize;
            ChannelStats.FrameCount++;
        }
        UpdateStatistics();
    }
```

And the update statistics function:

```
    private void UpdateStatistics()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new UpdateDelegate(UpdateStatistics));
        }
        else
        {
            lock (ChannelStats)
            {
                FrameCapturedLabel.Text = string.Format("Frames Captured: {0}", ChannelStats.FrameCount);
                TotalCapturedLabel.Text = string.Format("Total Captured: {0} [MB]", (double)ChannelStats.TotalSize / 1000000.0);
                CurrentFileLabel.Text = string.Format("Current File Size: {0} [MB]", (double)ChannelStats.CurrentFileSize / 1000000.0);
                FileCountLabel.Text = string.Format("File Count: {0}", ChannelStats.FileCount); 
            }                      
        }
    }
```

The code runs successfully for a random number of frames (usually 5-15) before it crashes with an access violation exception. Unfortunately this is being run on a remote, embedded system and as such I don't have my debugger handy to help me. Also of note:

- Running the above code, without calling UpdateStatistics(), works fine.
- Running a similar program in a C++ Win32 Console Application works fine.

So my question: Any hints on what might be causing an access violation? Is the locking in the code reasonable, or is it totally off?

Any input is much appreciated!

**Edit**

The ChannelStats variable is defined as follows:

```
    private class RecordStatistics
    {
        public Int64 TotalSize { get; set; }
        public Int64 CurrentFileSize { get; set; }
        public Int64 FileCount { get; set; }
        public Int64 FrameCount { get; set; }

        public RecordStatistics()
        {
            TotalSize = 0;
            CurrentFileSize = 0;
            FileCount = 0;
            FrameCount = 0;            
        }
    }

    RecordStatistics ChannelStats;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is ChannelStats?  Is that your class?  It is better if you do locking on separate object.

```
private static object _thisLock = new object();

lock (_thisLock)
{
    // Critical code section
}
```

Comment: ChannelStats is a simple structure for maintaining the statistics, I've added an update.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. The reason I added locking was in case accessing the ChannelStats object b/w the callback thread and the Form thread was causing an access violation. So I want to ensure that only one thread can access this variable at a time. In your example above, if thisLock is a local variable how can it help us?

Comment: @DeusAduro, thisLock should be class variable variable, not local.  Check this example from MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Ok its making a little more sense now. However the ChannelStats variable itself is a class variable. It should function the same as in your example. I did however try using a seperate object for the lock (as in the MS example). The same issue is cropping up though. I think the issue may not be in the synchronization but something different. I mean even without locking I don't know how the ChannelStats variable could cause an AV...

Comment: @DeusAduro - could you please post whole AV trace stack.  Also do you have any information in EventVewer?

Comment: @DeusAduro, try to use static object instead.  Check my code I changed for static, this way you will escape deadlock.

Comment: Whats the best way to get a stack trace? I don't have a debugger on the embedded system. I've never actually done debugging without the VS environment.

Comment: @DeusAduro I don't know much about embedded systems, but can you try Remote Debugging from VS?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx  I think there should be some remote debugging via VS.